# How to draw a drawable onto a canvas?

Tags: android, itemtouchhelper

I have made a class `SwipeController` class which extends `Callback`.

`onChildDraw` is as follows:

```
@Override
    public void onChildDraw(Canvas c,
                            RecyclerView recyclerView,
                            RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder,
                            float dX, float dY,
                            int actionState, boolean isCurrentlyActive) {
        drawButtons(c, viewHolder);
        if (actionState == ACTION_STATE_SWIPE) {
            setTouchListener(c, recyclerView, viewHolder, dX, dY, actionState, isCurrentlyActive);
        }
        super.onChildDraw(c, recyclerView, viewHolder, dX, dY, actionState, isCurrentlyActive);
    }
```

`drawButtons` method is as follows:

```
private void drawButtons(Canvas c, RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder) {
        float buttonWidthWithoutPadding = buttonWidth - 20;
        float corners = 2;

        View itemView = viewHolder.itemView;
        Paint p = new Paint();

        RectF leftButton = new RectF(itemView.getLeft(), itemView.getTop(), itemView.getLeft() + buttonWidthWithoutPadding, itemView.getBottom());
        p.setColor(Color.BLUE);
        c.drawRoundRect(leftButton, corners, corners, p);
        drawText("EDIT", c, leftButton, p);

        RectF rightButton = new RectF(itemView.getRight() - buttonWidthWithoutPadding, itemView.getTop()+20, itemView.getRight()-20, itemView.getBottom()-20);
        p.setColor(Color.RED);
        c.drawRoundRect(rightButton, corners, corners, p);
        drawText("DELETE", c, rightButton, p);

        buttonInstance = null;
        if (buttonShowedState == ButtonsState.LEFT_VISIBLE) {
            buttonInstance = leftButton;
        }
        else if (buttonShowedState == ButtonsState.RIGHT_VISIBLE) {
            buttonInstance = rightButton;
        }
    }
```

Now this works fine as expected. But I want to use drawable images instead of just simple text on the buttons. Is there a way to do it? Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: What are you asking, exactly? How to draw images to a `Canvas`?

Comment: Yes. I have tried some answers but did not get the solution with any. Maybe I am missing something.

Comment: did you check `Drawable` class API documentation? if so, what's unclear?

Comment: The thing is its kind of silly. I have seen the documentation also. I actually don't know how to reach to my drawable files. `Drawable` needs `android.graphics.drawable`. And `R.drawable.some_drawable` gives `int`. I am using this swipe thing for the very first time.

Comment: is `R.drawable.some_drawable` a png/jpg/gif image?

Comment: its an xml file.

Comment: with what first root tag?

Comment: its an `vector` drawable. So vector is the root tag.

Comment: then use `Resources#getDrawable` method to get your `Drawable`